# How do I alternate a label and a custom view in a StackLayout?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a layout for a group edit page that contains 3 custom views and a label for each one:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:...;assembly=..."
             xmlns:view="clr-namespace:...;assembly=..."
             x:Class="..."
             Title="Configure Group">
  <ScrollView>
    <StackLayout Padding="20">
      <Label Text="Person 1" Font="Large"/>      
      <view:EditPersonView/>
      <Label Text="Person 2" Font="Large"/>
      <view:EditPersonView/>
      <Label Text="Person 3" Font="Large"/>
      <view:EditPersonView/>
    </StackLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

EditPersonView.cs

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                   xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:...;assembly=..."
                   x:Class="...EditPersonView">
    <ContentView.BindingContext>
        <vm:PersonViewModel/>
    </ContentView.BindingContext>
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Label Text="Date of Birth"/>
            <DatePicker Date="{Binding DateOfBirth, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Label Text="Gender"/>
            <Picker x:Name="GenderPicker"
                    SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedGenderIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Label Text="Smoking Habit"/>
            <Picker x:Name="SmokingHabitPicker"
                    SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedSmokingHabitIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

When this is rendered I get all 3 labels at the top followed by the 3 custom views and not the expected Label then custom view pattern.  How do I get the alternating pattern that I am expecting?

Comment: What does EditPersonView look like?  I would expect this to work

Comment: Are you using the latest `Xamarin.Forms`'s version available on nuget (1.2.2.6243) ? If yes, this might be a bug.

Comment: Indeed. The code seems right.